# Prove that for an arbitrary (possibly infinite) language, that for a finite L-structure $M$, if $M \equiv N$ then $ M \cong N$

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> Prove that for an arbitrary (possibly infinite) language, that for a finite L-structure $M$, if $M \equiv N$ then $ M \cong N$

I'm struggling to think of what to do, I presume the best thing is to keep it simple and assume the Language to only be relational.

I'd start by assuming we have a finite Language and taking $|M|$ = k = $|N|$ and as I've assumed the language to only be relational and finite take {$R_1,...,R_p$} to be the relation symbols. I'm guessing I need to show that there is some sentence $\sigma$ that is true in both $M$ and $N$? I have no idea what that sentence would be could someone help me out? Thanks.

Also how would I even begin to answer it in the infinite case?

Comment: I think we want the language to have equality.

Comment: I think that you have to use the "back-and-forth" technique; see David Marker, [Model theory : An introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=QieAHk--GCcC&pg=PA48) (2002), **Ch.2.4 Back and Forth**, page 48.

Comment: What do $\equiv$ and $\cong$ denote?

Comment: @goblin: elementary equivalence and isomorphism. This is standard notation.

Comment: @tomasz: there is no assumption about completeness in this question. So how can it be a duplicate of that question about complete first-order theories?

Comment: @RobArthan: Because the theory of any model is complete?

Comment: @tomasz: I was looking for that question originally, but couldn't remember where to find it exactly!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It took me some time to find that, too. In the end, I searched the list of questions I have answered with model-theory tag one by one. I was about to give up, too.

Comment: @tomasz - Sorry I haven't had a chance to attempt answering this question, but if it does end up being a duplicate I will delete. Thanks!

Comment: The question isn't right; if the language has only one unary relation symbol $R$, then every model in which $R$ holds of every element is elementarily equivalent to every other model in which $R$ holds of every element. The language needs to have equality for the answers to apply, but that isn't an arbitrary language.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=a_1,\dots,a_k$ be an enumeration of $M$ and let $p(x)={\rm tp}_M(a)$. By construction $p(x)$ is consistent in $M$, then $p(x)$ is finitely consistent in any $N\equiv M$. As $N$ is also finite, $p(x)$ is realized in $N$, say by the tuple $b$. Then $a\mapsto b$ is the required isomorphism.

Comment: Excuse me, but what ${\rm tp}(a)$ does it mean ?

Comment: Correction: add $M$ as subscript. ${\rm tp}_M(a)={\rm tp}_M(a/\varnothing)$ is the type of $a$ in $M$ over the empty set.

Comment: Cf., for example, section 4.1 of Marker's book (in my edition, just above definition 4.1.2).

Comment: The question doesn't say that $N$ is finite. (If either $M$ or $N$ is finite, the problem is much easier.)

Comment: If $M\equiv N$ then $M\models\exists^{=n}x\ x=x$ if and only if  $N\models\exists^{=n}x\ x=x$.

Comment: The question doesn't explicitly state that the language has the equality relation. This answer is correct with that extra assumption.